# Non-Google "Find My Phone" for Android devices?

Tags: android, security

I like to find non-Google alternatives to apps when possible. I'm looking for an app that provides a "Find my phone" feature - showing the location on a map, and activating the device ringer at full volume - and a way to remotely wipe a lost device.

Open-source apps are preferable, but I don't think there is one. Paid apps are ok - perhaps preferable, since they're less likely to have creepy privacy-violating features.

The only app I've found so far is Avira. It has "find my phone" built-in, but no remote wipe feature. The "find my phone" map view works well, but the "play sound" feature isn't great - it plays a very loud, annoying sound for 20 seconds, but unlike Google's app, you can't cancel the sound when you find the device - you have to continue listening to the loud, annoying sound until it runs its course.

**Summed up, my requirements are:**

- an Android app that lets me remotely find my "lost phone"
- must work without any Google services
- must show the location of my device on a map
- must allow to activate the device ringer at full volume (regardless of "silent mode" etc)
- must provide a feature to remotely wipe the device
- must **not** violate my privacy (i.e. not contain creepy calling-home, ads, analytics etc)
- open source preferred. If no such exist, paid apps are acceptable

Comment: [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154). But you can [find a list in my app listings for anti-theft](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_antimalware#group_448). I didn't try any of those, so I cannot give a clear recommendation; however, *Cerberus* is often held high, as is *Prey*.

Comment: @Izzy: The first link in your comment, about whether list questions are acceptable on stack exchange sites, says, "A new SE is now available for just this sort of thing: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com" - and that's where we are! :)

Comment: Also, this site's help starts with: "This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, 'what software can I use to do …?'." That's exactly what I'm asking for. I can reword the question to avoid using the specific word "list," but any such question is essentially asking for a list of all software that satisfy the given criteria.

Comment: Josh, that "a new site…" is a comment by a low rep user, not even upvoted once. And no, it does not mean we accept "list type questions" here. I didn't say your question is off-topic (if it were, I had closed it) – but please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and see if you can [edit] and improve your question to make it as specific as possible. The more specific your question is tailored to your needs, the more the answers can be ;) Maybe it's just a little formatting, let me see…

Comment: OK, my apologies: it seems it was just the "I'm looking for a list" part that got me triggered. As I said, we don't support that list stuff ;) I slightly adjusted your post. Can you please check if it's OK for you this way? // As for the privacy part (my speciality): I recommend open-source, as there exists the possibility to check for "calling-home and backdoor stuff". And definitely nothing with ad modules or the like (which is why I introduced that explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

**Lookout Security** may be a good fit for what you want.

The free version will give you:

> ►FIND MY PHONE
>   • Locate & Scream: Map the location of your device and make it sound
>      an alarm - even when it is on silent!
>   • Signal Flare: Automatically
>      save your device’s location when the battery is low

And if you pay for "Lookout Premium" you get also:

> ►Theft Alerts: Get an email with a photo and location whenever
>   suspicious behavior is detected that could mean it has been stolen
>   ►Lock & Wipe: Remotely lock your device, post a custom message and
>   erase your data

You can download it from the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout

Answer (score 1):

Indeed [Cerberus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsdroid.cerberus&hl=en) is a good candidate.

> Cerberus is a complete anti-theft application, the best protection you
>   can get to recover your misplaced, lost or stolen Android device. It's
>   not just a "find my phone" app or a phone tracker, Cerberus has many
>   unique features that make it the perfect app to locate your phone or
>   tablet, identify the thief and get back your device.

It has the following features:

- Remote control through the website https://www.cerberusapp.com
- Remote control via SMS (text messages) from another phone
- Automatic alerts

Advanced features

- Locate devices on map
- Start alarm
- Lock and Wipe data
- Take pictures of the thief
- Backup your data
- Android Wear support
- Remote Unix-like shell

Screenshots:

[image: a]

*Source: https://www.cerberusapp.com/home/en*